# JIT compile for AngularJS Tree directive and click events

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I've been looking for a good angular directive to handle all our requirements:

- Bind to very large data structure (approx 4MB of json)
- Display checkboxes for each node
- Provide events when nodes are selected.

In the end I've been working on writing my own one. Writing a directive to generate the tree wasn't too difficult with a little help from Stackoverflow, however when it is bound to a large data source it is very slow because it compiles and builds the entire tree. I was wondering if someone could help me so that the subtrees are compiled / rendered on expansion rather that all at the start.

I've also been struggling to hook up the click event so that it fires on selection of a node.

I've created a fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/markritchie/jdrnau3d/) to demonstrate the problems. I've kept the data small so it loads quickly but I can create a large data set if needed. Here's the current code for the directive

```
app.directive('simpleTree', function() {
    var directive = {
        template: '<div style="margin-top: 5px;"><div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-7"><div class="input-group"><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Filter" ng-model="searchFilter"><div class="input-group-btn"> <span class="btn btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-filter" style="font-size:14px; height:20px"></span></span></div></div></div>' +
        '<div simple-tree-root class="col-sm-12" ng-model="tree" search-text="searchFilter" style="margin-top: 5px;"></div><div data-ng-show="tree.length == 0" class="col-sm-12">No items to display</div></div>',
        replace: true,
        transclude: true,
        scope: {
            'tree': '=ngModel',
            'clickEventHandler': '&nodeClick'
        },
        restrict: 'AE',
        link: function($scope, element, attrs) {
        }
    };
    return directive;
});

 app.directive('simpleTreeRoot', function() {
    var directive = {
        template: '<ul class="simple-tree"><div choice ng-repeat="choice in tree | filter:searchText"></div></ul>',
        replace: true,
        transclude: true,
        scope: {
            'tree': '=ngModel',
            'searchText': '=',
            'clickEventHandler': '&nodeClick'
        },
        restrict: 'AE'
    };
    return directive;
});


app.directive('choice', function($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        transclude: true,
        template: '<li><span><i class="glyphicon" data-ng-class="choice.expanded ? \'glyphicon-minus\' : \'glyphicon-plus\'"  data-ng-show="choice.items.length > 0" ng-click="choice.expanded = !choice.expanded" ></i></span>' +
                    '<label data-ng-click="clickEventHandler(choice.text)" class="col-sm-12">{{choice.text}}</label></li>',
        link: function(scope, elm, attrs) {

            //Add children by $compiling and doing a new choice directive
            if (scope.choice.items && (scope.choice.items.length > 0)) {
                var childChoice = $compile('<div simple-tree-root ng-model="choice.items" data-ng-show="choice.expanded"></div>')(scope);
                elm.append(childChoice);
            }
        }
    };
});
```

If someone knows about an existing directive that does all this I'd be happy to use it or if there's not and people are interested I can speak to people here to see if we can open source for everyone to use / contribute.

Answer (score 1):

Just add a watcher:

```
if (scope.choice.items && (scope.choice.items.length > 0)) {
  scope.$watch('choice.expanded', function(newValue) {
  if (newValue) {
    var childChoice = $compile('<div simple-tree-root ng
```

Comment: That works nicely for the JIT rendering, but I'm still not sure how to get the click event on selection of a treenode. Any help here would be greatly appreciated

Comment: @Mark You can broadcast an event in the watcher and react to that event in your controller, instead of passing an event handler. That's the simplest solution. If you don't want that then I would let `simpleTreeRoot` have an inherited scope. An isolated one doesn't make much sense, since `simpleTree` is isolated anyway. That way you'd have `clickEventHandler` directly available in your `choice` directive.